# Could anyone experienced tell me if i have any obvious flaws in my smart contract please

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, security

I am very new to solidity, i have been playing around for about a week now and have created my first "good" bit of code i want to turn into a dapp. I would just like to see from a experts point of view if there is any security flaws in the code before i continue to add more features. I appreciate any feedback.

Would also like to add i do have the safemath library in the contract just wasn't worth posting with the code below.

```
contract CannonMultiSender {

using SafeMath for uint256;

address public owner;
uint16 public arrayLimit = 150;
uint256 public feePerAddrs = 0.01 ether;

mapping(address => uint256) public txCount;


event EthAirdrop(address indexed by, uint256 totalTransfers, uint256 ethValue);

event FeeChanged(uint256 from, uint256 to);
event FeesClamied(address by, uint256 amount);
event SentChange(address to, uint256 amount);

constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

// Multi value sender
function multiValeEthAirdrop(address[] memory _to, uint256[] memory _amount) public payable {
    uint256 totalEthValue = _getTotalEthValue(_amount);
    uint256 dynamicFee = feePerAddrs.mul(_to.length);
    uint256 totalCost = totalEthValue.add(dynamicFee);

    require(_to.length <= arrayLimit, "You can only transfer to >= 150 accounts at a time due to gas limits.");
    require(_to.length == _amount.length, "The amount of recepients and values must be the same,");
    require(totalCost <= msg.value, "Not enough funds to complete transaction.");

    uint8 i = 0;
    for (i; i < _to.length; i++) {
        payable(_to[i]).transfer(_amount[i]);
    }

    txCount[msg.sender]++;
    giveChange(totalCost);

    emit EthAirdrop(msg.sender, _to.length, totalEthValue);
}

function singleValueEthAirdrop(address[] memory _to, uint256 _amount) public payable {
    uint256 dynamicFee = feePerAddrs.mul(_to.length);
    uint256 totalCost = _amount.mul(_to.length).add(dynamicFee);
    
    require(_to.length <= arrayLimit, "You can only transfer to >= 150 accounts at a time due to gas limits.");
    require(totalCost <= msg.value, "Not enough funds to complete transaction.");

    uint8 i = 0;
    for (i; i < _to.length; i++) {
        payable(_to[i]).transfer(_amount);
    }

    txCount[msg.sender]++;
    giveChange(totalCost);

    emit EthAirdrop(msg.sender, _to.length, _amount.mul(_to.length));
}

// Sums total value of a transaction
function _getTotalEthValue(uint256[] memory _values) internal pure returns(uint256) {
    uint256 totalVal = 0;
    for(uint i = 0; i < _values.length; i++) {
        totalVal = totalVal.add(_values[i]);
    }
    return totalVal;
}

// Transfers any change back to sender
function giveChange(uint256 _price) internal {
    if(msg.value > _price) {
        uint256 change = msg.value.sub(_price);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(change);

        emit SentChange(msg.sender, change);
    }
}

// Change the fee
function changeFeePerAddrs(uint256 _newFee) public onlyOwner {
    feePerAddrs = _newFee;

    emit FeeChanged(feePerAddrs, _newFee);
}

// Claim fees
function claimFees(uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
    require(address(this).balance >= _amount, "Not enough funds to withdraw.");
    payable(owner).transfer(_amount);

    emit FeesClamied(msg.sender, _amount);
}

// Get the balance of the contract
function getContractBal() public view returns (uint256) {
    return (address(this).balance);

}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "This function is for the owner only.");
    _;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To check if your dapp has any vulnerability, you can use took called `slither`. It is free, open source and very easy to use. Here is the [github](https://github.com/crytic/slither).

Comment: Appreciate it, if i had enough rep id upvote you !!!